# Позиционирование баннера

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Имеется адаптивный блок(`display:flex`), с моим экраном примерно 1100 на 800, в котором есть дочерний блок, занимающий размеры родителя(`display:block`), а внутри него циклом формируются элементы, в 4 колонки(`column-count: 4;`), которые занимают всю ширину родителя. Элементы могут быть длиньше, короче, и т.д. От этого ширина не зависит. [image: Выглядит это примерно вот так]

Мне нужно вставить банер в верхний правый угол блока, так, чтобы остальные элементы его обтекали. Самой большой проблемой для меня стало то, что эти блоки формируются циклом, и их может быть как очень мало так и очень много, поэтому, я думаю, что нужно добавить новый блок в родителя и что-то делать уже с ним, но не могу додуматься, что именно. Рисунки конечно кривые, но схематичные, нужно чтобы банер вот так располагался.[image: Вот нужно чтоб где красный элемент был баннер]